# UnicodeEncodeError when __str__ already returns unicode

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode

We have the following formatted string:

```
'{}: {}.'.format(message, object)
```

Which raises:

```
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 0-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

The object's string is non-ascii, but the method is overriden so that it returns a unicode string:

```
def __str__(self):
    return unicode(self.name)
```

Why then is a `UnicodeEncodeError` being raised? What can I do to fix it?

I have tried turning the string into a unicode one:

```
u'{}: {}.'.format(message, object)
```

But that messes up the object's string. It returns `\xf1\xf1\xf1\xf1` instead of `ññññ`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, normal strings are byte strings. And `__str__` should **never** return an unicode string: you are breaking the `str` contract. If you need unicode conversion for your object use the `__unicode__` special function:

```
def __unicode__(self):
    return unicode(self.name)
```

or even better `return self.name.decode(encoding)` where encoding is the encoding of `self.name`.

And never mix unicode strings and byte strings without explicit encoding. So the correct way is:

```
'{}: {}.'.format(message, unicode(object).encode(encoding))
```

Here again, encoding represents what you want for the external representation. Common encodings are `Latin1` or `cp1252` on Windows, and often `utf-8` on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I recommend function `decode` and `encode`, as follow:

```
class A(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "速度快".decode("utf-8", "ignore")

obj = A()
print u"{}".format(obj)
```

add `u`